# Короткое тире

Tags: пунктуация

Объясните, пожалуйста, когда употребляется именно оно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короткое цифровое тире (без пробелов) всегда употребляется между цифрами: 3–5 лет. Длина пунктуационного тире (с пробелами) - вопрос вкуса.

Answer (score 0):

Кроме *поезда Москва – Владивосток*, даже и не знаю...

Comment: А мне казалось, там тоже длинное.